# If control is not visible, set value to null (access VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a number of controls on it. However, if the user marks an option button as "Not Due", many of these fields are set to not be visible. Ultimately I don't want these hidden fields to store any value, but I don't want the values to disappear until the form is saved (that way if someone accidentally hits "not due", it doesn't erase all of the information). This is the code I have-- set to run on all controls before the form updates.

It's telling me that the "Object doesn't support this property or method" and highlights ctl.Value = null when I debug. Any idea what I can do to make this work?

```
Dim ctl As Control
    If Me.optPayDue = 2 Then
        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
            If ctl.Visible = False Then ctl.Value = Null
        Next ctl
    End If
```

Comment: Not quite familiar with Access so I'm possibly talking out of my ...mug, but I don't think `Null` is a valid value to assign a control. Also `If ctl.Visible = False Then` should be `If Not ctl.Visible Then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because things included in the `Controls` collections are like Subforms, Labels, EmptyCells, etc. which do not have a `Value` property.

You want to check that the thing for which you are setting the value has a `Value` property before acting on it.

```
Dim ValueControls As New Dictionary
ValueControls.Add "TextBox", "TextBox"
ValueControls.Add "CheckBox", "CheckBox"
ValueControls.Add "ComboBox", "ComboBox"
ValueControls.Add "ListBox", "ListBox"
ValueControls.Add "OptionButton", "OptionButton"

Dim ctl As Control
If Me.optPayDue = 2 Then
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If Not ctl.Visible and ValueControls.Exists(TypeName(ctl)) Then 
            ctl.Value = Null
        End If
    Next ctl
End If
```

To use the `Dictionary` class you need to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll)

[image]

Comment: Dim ValueControls As New Dictionary is giving me the compile error "user-defined type not defined" :/

Comment: If I just go to Tools > References and check Microsoft Scripting Runtime, will this program still function correctly on someone else's computer or do I have to reference it explicitly in the code? It works, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to reference that in my code :)

Comment: Actually, it appears to have worked when I do "Dim ValueControls As Object" and then "Set ValueControls = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")" followed by your ValueControls.Add code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Eleyna You shouldn't need to use late binding (`CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` ). This reference should work on anyone's computer because it comes with Windows. I'm wondering if the reason you couldn't declare as `Dictionary` is because there is a compile error elsewhere. Do you have `Option Explicit` set (and automatically set) in every module/class? Does your project compile?

Comment: I do not have it set as explicit for one class because it doesn't allow my to turn my warnings off and on, but otherwise, yes. Explicit is set for all other classes and modules.

Comment: @Eleyna warnings as in `DoCmd.SetWarnings`? This is pretty off topic for your current question but I'd say if you are using that you should reconsider/find a work around. There are 90% of the time better ways.

Comment: Yes, I use it because I have to run two queries to append and delete records to a table from a staging table. I'm not sure how else to go about it, but I turn off warnings directly beforehand and as soon as the queries have run, the warnings are turned back on.

Comment: @Eleyna I assume that means you're suing `DoCmd.RunSQL`. If you use `CurrentDb.Execute` you don't have to turn off warnings (which if left off because an error happens during RunSQL all sorts of weird things can happen). The added benefit with `Currentdb.Execute` is you can see `CurrentDb.RecordsAffected` to QC what your query did.

Comment: I'm actually using OpenQuery to access a predefined query I made, but I suppose if it's safer to operate using Currentdb.Execute I could move my query into my code instead...hm... thanks so much for the tips. You're incredibly helpful! I don't have VBA best practices down yet, so this is good to know :P

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to weed out any controls that don't have a .Value in your for loop.  Assuming it is just textboxes you can do the following

```
    Dim ctl As Control
    If Me.optPayDue = 2 Then
        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
            If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox and ctl.Visible = False Then
            ctl.Value = Null
        Next ctl
    End If
```

For something like a checkbox the control type will be acCheckBox and the value would be set to 0.